# Using a Combo Box as a data entry on Access Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, drop-down-menu, combobox

I was wondering if you can use a Combo Box on a form in access as a data entry for a query.

For instance, I have a form based on a query and I want to use a Combo Box to edit a field that is blank on the query end based on the values that are in the Combo box, similar to a drop-down box in a query or table.

I created a Column for the data values to be entered and the values will go into a given based on the record page the combo box selection is made on.

I can add additional information if needed.

Comment: Sorry - as written and edited it makes no sense to me. But you can certainly base a form on a query - and you can edit fields on that form which will change the data in the underlying query. But this is simple to figure out for yourself by trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused here, but it sounds like you want to use a pass a parameter into a query.  Is that right?  Something like this, right.

[image]

If this is going in the direction you want, read through the links below, and download the sample files at the bottom of the URL.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut17a.htm

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut18.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a base query that will contain all of your data, Then for each combo box you will need to recreate and run the query. I usually program this on the after update event. I also create and store the query so that when a user returns to the form it returns to the same data as before. Just be warned that this could cause errors when the query is executing and updating subforms.

Example on your Form

```
'Assumes Combo1 has the data to filter and Table1 is source and Query1 exists
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()
  Dim Obj_QueryDef As Object
  Dim Temp_QueryName As Variant

  'Save Query Name for refreshing Form Data (Query will be overwritten!)
    Temp_QueryName = Me.Form.RecordSource
  'dereference the query definition object that already exists
    Set Obj_QueryDef = Me.Form.Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).QueryDefs(Temp_QueryName)
  'For Number Key
    Obj_QueryDef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [Field1] = " & Combo1 & ";"
  'Reset the Record Query then repaint the form
    Me.Form.RecordSource = Temp_QueryName
    Me.Form.Repaint
End Sub

'To add Add More Combo Boxes, After update Regenerate SQL adding & " AND Field2 = " Combo2 & ";"
'Or better yet Create a Function that handles the SQL statement
'You can use the same idea to limit the items that appear in the dropdown selection if you update
'   the record source for the combobox
'reference for different data types:
'String Data 'String Value' use chr(39) = '
'Obj_QueryDef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = " & Chr(39) & Combo1 & Chr(39) & ";"
'For Date Use #Date Time# Use chr(35) = #
'Obj_QueryDef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = " & Chr(35) & Combo1 & Chr(35) & ";"
```